# Lost or wrong jotted seed - is it possible to withdraw IOTA?

Tags: wallet, seed

Afraid of spyware or something worse, I decided to jot down the seed for my very first IOTA wallet. Unfortunately it was the wrong seed... Fortunately, it was a small amount of money I sent.
In possession of the address with which the coins were send from a cryptocurrency trading platform (i.e. bitfinex) to the unknown wallet, is it possible to withdraw the coins to the trading platform or even transfer it to my wallet in which I jotted down the seed correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, if you have no access to the seed, it is impossible to obtain the funds. That is why doing what you did (sending test amounts) is a good habit.